# Derivative of absolute value in PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The following equations are on page 23 in "David Gilbarg, Neil S. Trudinger Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order, 2nd edition"

$$ \Gamma(x) = \Gamma(|x|) :=
 \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{n(2-n)w_n} |x|^{2-n} & n > 2 \\
  \frac 1 {2\pi} \log |x| & n=2
 \end{cases}$$

$$ D_i \Gamma(x-y) = \frac 1 {nw_n} |x-y|^{-n} (x_i - y_i) $$

My calculation shows
$$ D_i \Gamma(x-y) = \frac 1 {nw_n} |x-y|^{1-n} \frac{(x_i - y_i)(x-y)}{|x-y|} $$
This is derived by using $ |u|' = u u' / |u| $. What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a small mistake:
$$
D_i\Gamma(x-y)=\frac{1}{n(2-n)w_n}(2-n)|x-y|^{2-n-1}\frac{x_i-y_i}{|x-y|}=\frac{1}{nw_n}|x-y|^{-n}|x-y|\frac{x_i-y_i}{|x-y|}=\frac{1}{nw_n}|x-y|^{-n}(x_i-y_i)
$$

Comment: Thank you, but is it true that $D_i(|x-y|)= (x-y)(x_i-y_i)/|x-y| ?$

Comment: If yes, why is (x-y) not shown ?

Comment: As far as I know $D_i((|x_1-y_1|,\dots,|x_n-y_n|))=\frac{x_i-y_i}{(|x_1-y_1|,\dots,|x_n-y_n|)}$

Comment: My professor also say the above relation. I'm confused. In general, is it true that $|u|' = u/|u|$. ?

Comment: Sure, that holds when you derive a scalar function. Try to better understand how you can derive a multi-dimensional function. Of course, in your case you have all elements independent from each other, i.e. each component does not affect the others.

Comment: I know a little what I was thinking wrong. I'll try to think more. Thank you for your kindness!